# getAttribute() not working with Sizzle in IE 11

Tags: javascript, sizzle

I have some Javascript code that works fine on every other browser but (of course) IE. Could someone tell me if there is a problem with my code, and if there is not, suggest a fix?

**Note:** IE returns `null` for `href` attribute.

```
for(var a=Sizzle("*"),i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
  a[i].onclick=function(){
    window.open(this.getAttribute("href"),"_self");
  }
}
```

Comment: Knowing which version of IE would probably be helpful

Comment: @zerkms Every element in the DOM.

Comment: @Krii: And does every element in the DOM have an `href` property? (and note: `this` is not every element in the DOM, it's the one you clicked on).

Comment: why would you need this on every element in the dom when most don't have `href`? What does `doesn't work` mean? That is not a proper problem description

Comment: No... That may be the problem.

Comment: Since you can only work with the elements that have the `href` attribute, it would make sense to *use that in your selector*.

Comment: @charlietfl As is stated in the question IE returns `this.getAttribute` as `null`.

Comment: @Krii For what elements? A 5 word description to cover all possibilities is not clear at all

Comment: Try something like: `Sizzle("[href]")` for example to select *only* elements that actually have an `href` attribute.

Comment: @MattBurland This works (a little stupid on my part) post this as an answer and I will accept it (along with adding a slightly more descriptive title).

Comment: @Krii note that events bubble so what would also be happening is that same handler would be fired on all the parents , even if the target had an href

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try selecting only the elements that actually have an `href` property.

Something like:

```
for(var a=Sizzle("[href]"), i=0; i<a.length;i++) { ... }
```

The original cause of your problem is probably due to how event order is handled. See [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) for some background. You were adding event handlers to not just the links that actually have `href` properties but all their parents.

Either way there aren't too many cases for using the `*` selector versus something more specific. And you should, generally, use the most specific selector you can.